# Entries in cache are not evicted

Tags: infinispan

I'm using Infinispan ( 9.4.5.Final ) to store data locally in caches.

To do so, i'm using this piece of code ( from https://www.baeldung.com/infinispan)

```
private Configuration passivatingConfiguration() {
return new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .memory().evictionType(EvictionType.COUNT).size(1)
  .persistence() 
  .passivation(true)    // activating passivation
  .addSingleFileStore() // in a single file
  .purgeOnStartup(true) // clean the file on startup
  .location(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")) 
  .build();}
```

Each time I put something in the cache, i'm printing its size :

```
cache.size()
```

The cache size should be constant to 1 but it can't stop increasing...

I'm trying with another piece of code :

```
private Configuration evictingConfiguration() {
return new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .memory().evictionType(EvictionType.COUNT).size(1)
  .build();}
```

And... it's working... the size of the cache is always 1.

I want the memory to be fixed.
Does anymone experiencing the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You have configured a cache store. If you notice the size javadoc mentions it includes cache loaders in its invocation https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/10.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/Cache.html#size--

If you want to only retrieve the size of entries in memory try the following instead:

```
cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(Flag.SKIP_CACHE_LOAD).size();
```